# Postman can't handle JSON response with long string

Tags: json, mongodb, api, go, go-gin

I was building an API with GO that retrieves some data from a MongoDB database and responds with a JSON

So everything works fine until I put in the "Content" line, and the problem seems to be limited to Postman. Postman gets stuck in "Sending Request" if the Content line is too long.

```golang
type Article struct {
    Id      primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title   string             `json:"title,omitempty" bson:"title,omitempty"`
    Content string             `json:"content,omitempty" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    Imgurl  string             `json:"imgurl,omitempty" bson:"imgurl,omitempty"`
}

func ArticleById(c *gin.Context) {
    id, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(c.Param("id"))
    article := Article{}
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    collection.FindOne(ctx, Article{Id: id}).Decode(&article)

    //--------------------THIS WORKS FINE
    fmt.Println(article.Content)
    //--------------------THIS WORKS FINE TOO
    fmt.Println(gin.H{
        "article": gin.H{
            "title":   article.Title,
            "imgurl":  article.Imgurl,
            //---------THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
            "content": article.Content},
    })

    //--------------------THIS WORKS WITH SHORT STRINGS ONLY (IN POSTMAN)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "article": gin.H{
            "title":   article.Title,
            "imgurl":  article.Imgurl,
            //---------THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
            "content": article.Content},
    })
}
```

Here's a summary of the problem, what works and what doesn't.

- The issue doesn't seem like a database issue, I can directly print content
- I can print it after mapping it through gin.H
- Works fine if I omit "Content"
- Seems to work fine (with postman) even with content until the Content line reaches a certain length. shorter line works fine, even shorter multi-line texts work fine.
- Everything works fine if I hit it from a browser, only postman has issues.
- Works from CURL too
- Works fine when I use the same database from a Node.JS, Express api with postman.

Where exactly is the problem? What can I try?

Comment: If it is a Postman issue: hey not ask its authors? This question seems to be unrelated to programming.

Comment: I'm not certain whether it is a postman issue or whether I'm using postman wrong

Comment: Do more research about gin-gonic on how to bind json. some of their example code is using `c.BindJSON(&article)` c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"article": article.Content})

Comment: Works with a browser and works with curl is a strong hint that the server is not broken. So it is a Postman issue.